# How to get the current month and use in batch apex query

Tags: apex, soql, batch, datetime, schedulebatch

I want to get the current month from picklist field and use that current month in soql query in a batch class. I have written the following code and its not working.

```
String month = Product.Month__c.month();

Set<String> ple = new Set<String> {'Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'};

String query = 'Select Id, Name, Month__c from Product where CALENDAR_MONTH(Month__c) = :month';
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use a **[`Date Literal`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)** instead.

```
String query = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Month__c = THIS_MONTH';
```

Comment: That is 100% not true. I have used date literals all the time in batch queries.

Comment: But, I have tried in my code and it didn't work. So, I did it in another way.

Comment: Please note that the correct filter is `Month__c = THIS_MONTH`, not `CALENDAR_MONTH(Month__c) = THIS_MONTH` nor `Month__c = :THIS_MONTH`. But you have shared zero information about what you mean by *"didn't work"*, so all I can do is guess what problem you ran into.

Comment: When I run the batch job and schedule job I got an error in schedule job test class because of this date literals. So, I had to adapt the another way to solve the problem.

Comment: Tell me the exact error message if you want help...

Comment: I have used the exact filter what you have specified in the above answer. When I run my schedule job it has given me an error saying that "THIS_MONTH" should be in quotes. By using the below code I found the solution and my code is running perfectly now. But, Thank you so much for you answer because of your answer I came to know about the "Date Literals" topic and hope this will help me in future learnings as well.

Comment: It might be worth asking a separate, detailed question about why your date literals didn't work, including the *verbatim* error message along with complete code sample.

Comment: Well, then I will post a new question about that with stating the clear error message in it. Thank you.